# Test my js file loaded or not using phantom in play framework

Tags: java, playframework, phantomjs

I am using java play framework. How can I implement phantomJS to check whether my external js file is loading or not?

Comment: What external js? How do you use the play framework? What do you want to accomplish? What platform are you on? PhantomJS is not really usable on android.

Comment: i am on java platform. i am loading so many JS file in my project so i need to check that the JS file which i have been included are loading properly or not. for example when i logged in at that time 2-3 JS file are loading. i need to vheck that file are loading properly or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking about phantomjs, I suspect this is about running tests on your application.

You would need to write a phantomjs script. There are event listeners that you can use to detect if resources like referenced javascript files are loaded:

- Use [`page.onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html) when a resource for whatever reason cannot be loaded.
- Use [`page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) when you suspect a timeout.

Example:

```
page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
  if (resourceError.url.match(/\.js/)) {
    // only javascript
    console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
    console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
  }
};
```